# Scala initialization order

Tags: scala

In the Programming in Scala (Ch. 10 on "Composition & Inheritance") book there is an example which causes some misunderstandings. This is the extracted part:

```
abstract class Element {
  def contents: Array[String]
  val someProperty: String = {
    println("=== Element")
    contents(0)
  }
}

class UniformElement(
  str: String
) extends Element {
  val s = str
  println("=== UniformElement.s " + s)
  def contents = Array(s) // error
  //def contents = Array(str) // ok
}
val e = new UniformElement("str")
println(e.someProperty)
```

For some reason the initialization of superclass occures before `s` initialisation:

```
scala example.scala
=== Element
=== UniformElement.s str
null
```

Why does the alternative work without `s` (see commented line in code)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is field values are `null` until constructor completes, and super constructor is referencing indirectly value `s` which is initialised by child constructor, but the child constructor has not yet completed. The situation looks something like this

```
class UniformElement {
  def <init>(str: String) = {
    super.<init>()
    s = str
  }
}
```

where we can see if we replace `super.<init>()` with

```
val someProperty: String = {
  println("=== Element")
  contents(0)
}
```

that it executes before

```
s = str
```

[Initialisation order](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html) issues can often be addressed by changing eager `val s` into lazy like so

```
class UniformElement(str: String) extends Element {
  lazy val s = str
  println("=== UniformElement.s " + s)

  def contents = Array(s)
}
```

which now outputs

```
=== Element
=== UniformElement.s str
str
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the interesting question ! My guess (after spending some time on Scastie) would be this order of initialization :

1. **Arguments** : in your case, `str` is the first value to be defined
2. **Parent** : in your case, `Element`
3. **Child** : in your case, `UniformElement`

So, if I try to put it in a single class order, it goes like this :

```scala
class UniformElement{
  // Argument init
  val str = "str"
  // Super constructor
  def contents: Array[String]
  val someProperty: String = {
    println("=== Element")
    contents(0)
  }
  // Child constructor
  val s = str
  println("=== UniformElement.s " + s)
  def contents = Array(s) // error
  //def contents = Array(str) // ok
}
```

The trick is that, to init `someProperty`, scala need to evaluate `contents(0)` and find `contents` definition. But when finding definition, `s` is not yet defined (and `str` is).

So final 'runtime' process:

```scala
class UniformElement{
  // Argument init
  val str = "str"
  // Super constructor with contents replaced by definition
  val someProperty: String = {
    println("=== Element")
    Array(s)(0) // error : s doesn't exists !
    // Array(str)(0) // ok : str exists
  }
  // Child constructor
  val s = str
  println("=== UniformElement.s " + s)
  def contents = Array(s) // error
  //def contents = Array(str) // ok
}
```

To convince yourself, you can try :

```scala
println(e.someProperty) // null => s wasn't defined
println(e.contents(0)) // str => s is now defined
```

Feel free to ask for clarification if needed.